# How to iteratively make headings in R Quarto HTML?

Tags: html, r, quarto

I am creating a Quarto HTML document. I would like to dynamically create headings in the HTML.

I can get this to work:

````
```{r}
#| output: asis

strwrs = data(starwars)

TESTS <- starwars$homeworld %>% unique() %>% as.list()
  
for (i in 1:length(TESTS)){ 
  
  labvar <- TESTS[[i]]

  cat("### ",noquote(labvar),"\n")
  
  # differences against benchmark
  values <- starwars %>% filter(homeworld == labvar)
  
  #Character table
  info.table <- values %>%
  select(name, height, mass, skin_color, eye_color, birth_year, sex, gender)
  
  #Species distribution table
  coll.table <- values %>%
   select(species) %>%
    group_by(species) %>%
    summarize(distribution = n())
  
  cat(noquote("Character table"),"\n")
  print(htmltools::tagList(datatable(info.table)))
  
  cat(noquote("Distribution table"),"\n")
  print(htmltools::tagList(datatable(coll.table)))

  cat("\n","\n") 
} 

```
````

but when I try it on my data I get:

[image: errorimage]

what would be causing this? I do not understand why the code chunck works for one tibble but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can use R expressions in a header in Rmarkdown or quarto with:

```
### Fixed text `r computeHeader()`
```

Also, I would put the tables in different chunks, as I think quarto is assuming one table per chunk (unless you use the subtable YAML).